# Create square polygons from single centre coordinates and area in R

Tags: r, polygon, r-sp, centroid

I am having issues plotting true to geographic extent pixels in R. the files come with a list of daily single coordinates and pixel size (area). There is also a Z element separate from this. The data structure looks this way:

```
 X <- c(1,3,6,7)
 Y <- c(3,2,7,8)
 Z <- c(38,23,12,12)
 Area <- c(32,23,45,67)
```

The X and Y are in degrees longitude and latitude while the area is in square kilometres. I create the point features easily using:

```
library(sp)
A <- cbind(X,Y,Z,Area)
B <- SpatialPoints(A)
```

I plot these easily using the area values to determine the "cex" for plotting. The Z column is intensity and I use these values to determine the colours . How do I create spatial polygons features using the areas for each point in R? I would be using these points to create gridded rasters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(rgeos)      ## for gBuffer()
library(raster)     ## for bind()

ww <- sqrt(B$Area)/2  ## Widths of buffers needed to produce desired areas    

pp <- list()
for(i in seq_along(B)) {
    pp[i] <- gBuffer(B[i], width=ww[i], quadsegs=1, capStyle="SQUARE")
}
PP <- do.call(bind, pp)

## Check that it worked
plot(PP)
plot(B, add=TRUE)
text(B, labels=1:4, adj=c(-1,0), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh.  It worked. Where you have do.call(bind,res), I changed it to (bind,pp) for it to work.

Comment: @JokeO. - Ah, yes. Thanks for catching that.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to add the Z values to the polygons  before converting to raster, please?

Comment: @JokeO. -- Not before, but afterwards you can just do `SPP <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(PP, data.frame(B))`, after which `data.frame(SPP)` etc. will find the attached data.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this a bit, here is an sf solution.

Function to create the square buffers

```
bSquare <- function(x, a) {
  a <- sqrt(a)/2
  return( sf::st_buffer(x, dist = a, nQuadSegs=1, 
                        endCapStyle = "SQUARE") )
}
```

Some example data

```
library(sf)
xy <- st_as_sf(data.frame(x = c(1,3,6,7),
               y = c(3,2,7,8), z = c(38,23,12,12),
               area = c(32,23,45,67)),
               coords = c("x", "y"), 
               agr = "constant")
```

With variable buffer

```
sb.var <- bSquare(xy, xy$area)
  plot(st_geometry(sb.var))
    plot(st_geometry(xy), pch=20, add=TRUE)
```

[image: variable]

With fixed buffer

```
sb <- bSquare(xy, 32)
  plot(st_geometry(sb))
    plot(st_geometry(xy), pch=20, add=TRUE)
```

[image: fixed]